# Stopped discovering Printers

Tags: printing

Ubuntu 11.10 today on one machine has stopped discovering printers the tick is in the box and noone has changed the settings.  The CUPS print server is working fine as other ubuntu laptops see the printers and so does windows machines.  I have restarted cups on that machine but nothing seems to happen, it can see only the local usb printer and see the cups shared printers on the server but will not connect to them any idea please.

Comment: Close voters: This question has a good and accepted answer. There is no need to close this.

Comment: If this question were asked today it would be off topic but when it was asked 11.10 was supported and the answer may still be relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to answer this one, I figured out the problem, when I restarted the machine which has been running flawlessly for a few months now I forgot that I installed firestarter which blocked the ports to CUPS server.  Added the printer port and all is working fine now :)