# Stop Ubuntu discovering printers

Tags: printing

I have my machine connected to a large university network which means that Ubuntu has filled up my printers with other people's printers automatically (mostly MacBooks sharing their printers). This is irritating when I just want to print to the printers I've explicitly added but there are now lots and lots of printers in the list.

How can I stop this behaviour? I've already unticked View >> Discovered Printers.

Comment: This one has it the other way: http://askubuntu.com/questions/89276/stopped-discovering-printers  so.... block the ports >:D

Comment: Which ports? How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Out of curiosity, does /etc/cups/cupsd.conf contain the line "Browsing Off"? On mine it says so, and I don't see autodiscovered printers on my university network, but I couldn't remember if it was a change I made.

Comment: Yes, it has "Browsing Off" already.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to let CUPS not listen to port on the configure file, but CUPS stop working.

Finally, I copied my own printers and rename it with 0 as initial number. So they are at the top of the list.

This can fix it temporally.