# Printer settings replaced automatically

Tags: 14.04, printing

At work I print to a network printer, then release my print at any one of the hundreds of printers dotted around campus. The make and model show up as:

```
Sharp MX-5141N PS, 1.0
```

I set my computer up to connect to the printer on the appropriate URI using the `ldp:` protocol. I install the provided `ppd` driver. Once I've done this I can print to the network printers for a short time.

My question is that after a short amount of time (typically < 12 hours) Ubuntu automatically updates the printer I just set up and replaces the `ldp` with a local connection to the same printer shared through a colleague's MacBook. Through this indirect connect I can't (and don't want to) print.

How can I:

1. Stop Ubuntu replacing my printer configuration with the shared printer it finds?
2. Or, stop Ubuntu browsing for printers altogether (note: `Browsing Off` is already set in `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf`)

I've already checked out the responses to [Stop Ubuntu discovering printers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/376604/stop-ubuntu-discovering-printers) but this did not answer my question (I'm not looking to 'bump' my printer to the top of the list; I want to stop its settings being overridden).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured the issue out. When I set the printer up, I gave it the same name my colleague had (the default), so when rebooting this was updating my printer with my colleague's settings over the network.

To mitigate the issue, I set the printer up and gave it a unique name. This has now persisted through a couple of reboots, so I expect this has solved the problem (unless someone else on the network uses the name I've chosen!).